# Angular- Filter the data coming from the API and display it in a Mat-Data table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material-table

I need to display data in a **angular Mat data table** that are coming from the API.

Before showing it, I want to filter 3 data records and display the top ones.

As an example
`data = [ ['Admin user', '12'], ['Test User ', '2'], ['System user', '5'], ['Default user ', '66'], ['Jane user', '77'], ['Thomas', '77'] ]` 
From the above array, I need to show the **system user** first and then the **default user** and then the rest. How can I do that

The output should be in the following order

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| System User | 5 |
| Default User | 66 |
| Jane User | 77 |
| Admin user | 77 |

.. after rest

Comment: Just sort the response from api with rxjs map

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to sort on "another header"?

You should provide a name on that header cell.

```
 <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header="YOUR_NAME">
```

On mat-table tag you can provide a default header column like this

```
<mat-table matSortActive="YOUR_NAME" matSort>
```

For more info & examples:
https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview